# Three.js- How can I use device orientation as a first person control

Tags: javascript, mobile, three.js, device-orientation

I have a three.js scene that allows the user to roam about using custom keyboard controls(not using three.js library controls). For mobile devices, the user should be able to use [device orientation](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/DeviceOrientationControls.js) controls to maneuver around the scene similarly to the keyboard actions. I mainly see examples of device orientation with three.js orbitcontrols. How can I use device orientation to move the camera more freely similar to the keyboard controls? Below is the keyboard functions for the scene:

```
var keyboard = {};
        var player= {height:30, speed:10, turnSpeed:Math.PI*0.02};
  if(keyboard[87]){ // W key
    var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
    matrix.extractRotation( mesh.matrix );
    let axis = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,-1);
    axis = matrix.multiplyVector3(axis);
    camera.translateOnAxis(axis,player.speed);
    }
 if(keyboard[83]){ // S key
    var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
    matrix.extractRotation( mesh.matrix );
    let axis = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1);
    axis = matrix.multiplyVector3(axis);
    camera.translateOnAxis(axis,player.speed);
 }
   if(keyboard[65]){ // A key
    var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
    matrix.extractRotation( mesh.matrix );
    let axis = new THREE.Vector3(-1,0,0);
    axis = matrix.multiplyVector3(axis);
    camera.translateOnAxis(axis,player.speed);
  }
  if(keyboard[68]){ // D key
    var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
    matrix.extractRotation( mesh.matrix );
    let axis = new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0);
    axis = matrix.multiplyVector3(axis);
    camera.translateOnAxis(axis,player.speed);
}

 if(keyboard[39]){ // left arrow key
  camera.rotation.y -= player.turnSpeed;
 }
   if(keyboard[37]){ // right arrow key
  camera.rotation.y += player.turnSpeed;
 }
function device(){
if(window.DeviceOrientationEvent){
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function handleOrientation(event){
  var x = event.beta;
  var y = event.gamma;
  var z = event.alpha;
  if(x >90){x=90};
  if(x<-90){x=-90};
  x+= 90;
  y+= 90;

       if(x<50 && x>0){
         var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
       matrix.extractRotation( mesh.matrix );
       let axis = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,-1);
       axis = matrix.multiplyVector3(axis);
       camera.translateOnAxis(axis,player.speed);}
       if(y<0){
         var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
         matrix.extractRotation( mesh.matrix );
         let axis = new THREE.Vector3(-1,0,0);
         axis = matrix.multiplyVector3(axis);
         camera.translateOnAxis(axis,player.speed);
       }
       if(y>0){
         var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
         matrix.extractRotation( mesh.matrix );
         let axis = new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0);
         axis = matrix.multiplyVector3(axis);
         camera.translateOnAxis(axis,player.speed);
       }
       if(x>50 && x<90){
         var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
         matrix.extractRotation( mesh.matrix );
         let axis = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1);
         axis = matrix.multiplyVector3(axis);
         camera.translateOnAxis(axis,player.speed);
       }


})
}
 else{
alert("Sorry, your broweser doesn't support this game. Try it on Desktop.")
 }}
```

Comment: Not an answer: Use `camera.translateZ( distance )`. Also `translateX()`.

Comment: @WestLangley why?

Comment: How many `Matrix4`s and `Vector3`s are you instantiating per second when you hold down a key? The three.js methods I referenced are designed to be efficient.

Comment: @WestLangley Four and it crashed when adding camera.translateZ